# For loop with jquery avoiding to trigger more than one element

Tags: jquery, loops, hook, each

I'm trying to build a modal window with jquery and css which will be activated clicking a list element.
The effect that I want to achieve is a popup div in the middle of another div blurry effect, but for each list element I want to displayed only one div!! (I'm using a display none on the element to display, so if I click two list elements every box will be displayed near each other and the effect obtained will be very ugly).
Here's my code:
Liste Elements:

```
<div class="blabla" id="page-wrap">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li></li><li></li><li></li>....
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The modal div:

```
<div class="main">
                <div class="before-background"></div>
                <div class="modal">
                    <h1>Some Text</h1>
                    <p>Some other text</p>
                </div>
<div class="modal">
                    <h1>Some Text</h1>
                    <p>Some other text</p>
                </div>
<div class="modal">
                    <h1>Some Text</h1>
                    <p>Some other text</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

The javascript (I would like to use a .each function but I don't know how to connect each list with each div):

```
$("li:nth-child(1)").on("click", function() {
            $(".before-background").toggleClass("dialogIsOpen");
            $(".main .modal:nth-child(2)").toggleClass("modalEffect");
        });
        $("li:nth-child(2)").on("click", function() {
            $(".before-background").toggleClass("dialogIsOpen");
            $(".main .modal:nth-child(3)").toggleClass("modalEffect");
        });
```

.. and so on ..

And at the very end the css:

```
.modal {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #8dc63f;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    left: 22%;
    top: -90%;
    display: none;
    padding: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}
.dialogIsOpen {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(50%);
    /*-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);*/
}
.modalEffect {
    display: block!important;
    pointer-events: auto!important;
}
.before-background, .modal {
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 443px;
    width: 94.333333%;
    padding: 0;
}
.before-background {
    background-image: url(images/effect-image.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Any suggestion??

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use `nth-child` and instead use an explicit class that each `li` and `div` share. In other words, the first `li` might have a class of "modal-1" and its corresponding `div` would have the same class.

Comment: Why is there a shift in the child numbering: when you click on the first `li`, you want to use the second modal `div` ? Why not the first?

Comment: It was because of the dom: the DOM of this section is built in two containers, one for a sidebar (#page-wrap) and the other is the container of two main divs, the box with the text and a div on which will be fired the blur effect.
In the second section the first child is the actual div that contain the background image, for this reason there is a shift between the list elements and the divs on the other side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure only one `div` is made visible at a time, and use one event handler for all `li`, you could make use of:

- [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/): this gives an integer indicating the position of an element relative to its sibling elements. If you apply it to `this` you can know the number of the `li` that was clicked on.
- [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/): this reduces a set of elements to the one at the specified index. So you can "pick" a `div` like this based on an index.
- You don't use `.each()` for this, as you want to work with one `li` and `div` at a time

The event handler could look like this:

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
    var index = $(".dialogIsOpen").length 
            ? $(".main .modalEffect").index() - 1 // number of visible `div` 
            : $(this).index(); // number of clicked `li` element
    $(".main .modal").eq(index).toggleClass("modalEffect");
    $(".before-background").toggleClass("dialogIsOpen");
});
```

The above code will detect when a modal `div` is currently open, and if so the click will just close that one, no matter which `li` was clicked on. When no modal `div` is open, clicking a `li` will open the corresponding modal `div`.

You'll still have stuff to do to implement true modal behaviour, but I think the above answers your question about displaying only one `div`.